# Hacking TinyMCE for better usability (shortcodes and html)

Tags: jquery, tinymce, hacks

I'm looking for some theme or plugin examples that showcase ways in which to enhance the usability of editing shortcodes and/or custom html objects that have been inserted into the editor.

I know that its possible to apply runtime styles to elements (nextpage and image rollovers are a couple examples) and I'm looking for some examples of scripts that seek to extend this to other elements (custom classed divs for example).

I've never seen an example of shortcode editing that went beyond the basic bracket+properties+content.

Ideally, I'd like to see an example where someone has abstracted shortcodes into their html equivalent, with rollover and right click events to modify element attrributes.

Just looking for any examples of work in this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at my [Gridster Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cbach-wp-gridster/), it replaces every shortcode `[gridster id="" title=""]` with a visual replacement, like you know from the [gallery]-Shortcode.

[image]

To change parameters of the current shortcode, you're able to click a button and a tinyMCE modal will let you change anything within a user-friendly GUI.

[image]

The functions are based on the the way, the gallery-shortcode-replacement works.

If this points into the right direction, I could get in more detail if you want.

Comment: This is an amazingly good example, though it's pretty complex. Mind going into a bit of detail?